# Size calculation of node not as expected

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, size

I'm trying to place two similar shapes side by side and something exactly in between both. But instead the two shapes (`A` and `B`) overlap. `minimum size`s seem to be ignored here (was just for testing). I guess it has to do with the embedded `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\def\bracket{
  \draw[-] (1,0)--(0,0);
  \draw[-] (0,0)--(0,10);
  \draw[-] (0,10)--(1,10);

  \draw[-] (9,10)--(10,10);
  \draw[-] (10,10)--(10,0);
  \draw[-] (10,0)--(9,0);
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{every path}=[draw, line width=0.3mm];
\coordinate (v1) at (1,1) {};
\coordinate (v2) at (9,1) {};
\coordinate (v3) at (9,9) {};
\coordinate (v4) at (1,9) {};

\node (A) [minimum size=4cm]  {
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill [opacity=0.9,gray] (v2) \foreach \i in {3,4,1}{ -- (v\i) } -- cycle;
    \bracket
  \end{tikzpicture}
} ;
\node (B) [right of=A,minimum size=4cm]  {
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill [opacity=0.9,gray] (v2) \foreach \i in {3,4}{ -- (v\i) } -- cycle;
    \bracket
  \end{tikzpicture}
} ;
%\node (C) [right of=B] {
%  \begin{tikzpicture}
%    \fill [opacity=0.9,gray] (v2) \foreach \i in {4,1}{ -- (v\i) } -- cycle;
%    \bracket
%  \end{tikzpicture}
%} ;
\coordinate (AB) ($(A)!0.5!(B)$);
\node (a) at (AB) { \Large = };

%\coordinate (BC) ($(B)!0.5!(C)$);
%\node (a) at (BC) { \Large X };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Yes, one should not nest `tikzpicture`s.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This is probably related to your nested `tikzpictures`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not nest `tikzpicture`s. And there is no need for that, you could simply use `pics`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\def\bracket{
  \draw[-] (1,0)--(0,0);
  \draw[-] (0,0)--(0,10);
  \draw[-] (0,10)--(1,10);

  \draw[-] (9,10)--(10,10);
  \draw[-] (10,10)--(10,0);
  \draw[-] (10,0)--(9,0);
}
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
  my pic/.style={
    code={\coordinate (-v1) at (1,1);
        \coordinate (-v2) at (9,1);
        \coordinate (-v3) at (9,9);
        \coordinate (-v4) at (1,9);
        \fill [opacity=0.9,gray] (-v2) \foreach \i in {3,4,1}{ -- (-v\i) } -- cycle;
        \bracket
    }}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every path/.style={draw, line width=0.3mm}]
\pic[local bounding box=A]  at (0,0) {my pic};
\pic[local bounding box=B,right=4cm of A.south east] {my pic};
\pic[local bounding box=C,right=4cm of B.south east] {my pic};
\node[scale=3] (a) at ($(A.east)!0.5!(B.west)$) {$=$};
\node[scale=3] (b) at ($(B.east)!0.5!(C.west)$) {$\times$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, one may simplify this and make it a bit more flexible by allowing for parameters to be passed to the `pic`s.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
  my pic/.style={
    code={\coordinate (-v1) at (1,1);
        \coordinate (-v2) at (9,1);
        \coordinate (-v3) at (9,9);
        \coordinate (-v4) at (1,9);
        \fill [#1] (-v1) rectangle (-v3);
        \draw[-] (1,10) -| (0,0) -- (1,0);
        \draw[-] (9,10) -| (10,0) -- (9,0);
    }}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every path/.style={draw, line width=0.3mm}]
\pic[local bounding box=A]  at (0,0) {my pic={opacity=0.9,gray}};
\pic[local bounding box=B,right=4cm of A.south east] {my pic={opacity=0.9,gray}};
\pic[local bounding box=C,right=4cm of B.south east] {my pic={opacity=0.9,gray}};
\node[scale=3] (a) at ($(A.east)!0.5!(B.west)$) {$=$};
\node[scale=3] (b) at ($(B.east)!0.5!(C.west)$) {$\times$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Of course, you could also use nodes with `path picture`s, in which case the positioning will be a bit easier, and you could add some content to the nodes and play with `minimum size`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\tikzset{square with brackets/.style={minimum size=10cm,path picture={
 \fill[#1] ($(path picture bounding box.south west)!0.9!(path picture bounding
 box.north east)$) rectangle
 ($(path picture bounding box.north east)!0.9!(path picture bounding
 box.south west)$);
 \draw[ultra thick] 
 ($(path picture bounding box.south west)!0.1!(path picture bounding
 box.south east)$) -| (path picture bounding box.north west) --
 ($(path picture bounding box.north west)!0.1!(path picture bounding
 box.north east)$);
 \draw[ultra thick] 
 ($(path picture bounding box.south west)!0.9!(path picture bounding
 box.south east)$) -| (path picture bounding box.north east) --
 ($(path picture bounding box.north west)!0.9!(path picture bounding
 box.north east)$);
}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every path/.style={draw, line width=0.3mm}]
\node[square with brackets={opacity=0.9,gray}] (A){};
\node[square with brackets={opacity=0.9,gray},right=4cm of A] (B){};
\node[square with brackets={opacity=0.9,gray},right=4cm of B] (C){};
\node[scale=3] (a) at ($(A.east)!0.5!(B.west)$) {$=$};
\node[scale=3] (b) at ($(B.east)!0.5!(C.west)$) {$\times$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for (inclusive the equation, lol).